# Galaxy S7: Difference between various European versions

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s7

On Amazon France, once can [choose](https://www.amazon.fr/Samsung-Galaxy-S7-Smartphone-d%C3%A9bloqu%C3%A9/dp/B01BTZFM0W/?th=1) from the "France", "Germany" and "Italy" versions of the Samsung Galaxy S7 (not carrier locked).  They are priced slightly differently.

What is the difference between all these? Can't each be set to either language? Do they come with different software? Are they locked to a specific country in any way?

I am new to Android and I am confused about all the different versions each phone comes in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see are different versions of the exact same phone.
The non-french versions are import phones (it says it in their title).

With literally any european/international phone, the only differences are (from my experience):

- Different default language (makes sense, your phone will be in the language of the country you bought it in), this doesn't mean you can't change it; usually 99% of all languages are available.
- Different baseband: this is not very important for international variants, but carrier-exclusive models sometimes come with some bands disabled, so you can't use them on other carriers' networks.
- Pre-installed apps: Makes sense, in some countries some apps are predominantly used and in other countries other apps. This depends on local laws (what and how these apps are allowed to be offered) and local developers trying to get their app around using a different (often more expensive) way.
- Included accessories: Yes, sometimes you get more accessories (or extra accessories) in some country than in another. This may be a case, a screen protector etc.
- **Most important**: *Warranty*!
  Warranty is often bound to the country of sale. So you may need to send your phone via international parcel services, which you may need to pay on your own because they only cover national postage. Sometimes they may even deny warranty claims!

Important for you: Make sure the model number ends on an **F**.
Most Samsung devices in the last years changed their model no. from the GT-Ixxx(Y) to SM-xxxY, where x is a number and Y is a letter, **F** denotes *"international"*.

Comment: Thanks you for the response. I seems in the end it doesn't matter which one I get. Warranty should be valid everywhere within the European Economic Area (confirmed by Samsung website).  It is not mentioned if these are the F version but according to my research only the F version is sold in all three countries. I was unable to find what apps and accessories they come with, but I do not think it is the main reason for the different pricing: the same differences are there between the different colour versions.